# Multiple timestamps that need collection and totaling in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a system that logs employee computer clicks within a specific timeframe.  There are many values and I have been able to strip away information I do not need.  Each click is recorded with a timestamp and grouped by name.  I need to find the time spent with each person, grouped by last name.  I have tried and failed. :(
[Names & Timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daGMS.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you Everyone!
[Employee Audit Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBWgS.png) Column B = Action / Column D = Last name / Column F record a time employee creates an action.

Comment: Please post an example of what your desired output is

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hooded0ne:  I would like to get the sum of column C grouped together by the name in Column A.  A will always be grouped together, but the number of timestamps will vary per person.  This example and photo is "time spent with Patient"  (Crevier = 2:59 / Testa = 0:16 / Tattersall = 3:71)  The first timestamp for a name is the  sign-in.  The last is a sign-out.  The overall file is an employee audit.  Unfortunately the program collecting the data is dated.  It does not give me an total time.

Comment: @Community - I am not skilled enough to create a enough VBA code.  But I can input a larger scale photo for a better picture of what I am trying to accomplish.